# How to manage volume using FFMPEG

Tags: ffmpeg

Is there any way to set/modify/change/update volume of audio when it is playing using FFMPEG library. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

You can use ffmpeg's [volume](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#volume) filter. You'll probably want to search around to figure out how to get ffmpeg filters working in your application, but it's generally worth the effort.

You can also do it manually by multiplying the PCM data in the decoded audio data (AVFrame->data[0]) by your volume multiplier (>1.0 to increase volume, <1.0 to decrease volume), but then you'd need to know the format of your decoded data.

Comment: I am able to add "volume" filter and i am updating/setting new volume for decoded data but it is not effecting new volume value.

Comment: @SomashekharGanjigatti Without seeing your code there is nothing we can do to help.

Comment: Here is my code, I am setting new volume for decoded buffer.
'code'void FFMpegPlayer::UpdateVolumeForFrames(uint8_t* pStartFrame, uint8_t* pEndFrame, const float kfVolume)
{
if(kfVolume <= 0.0f)
{
memset(pStartFrame, 0, pEndFrame - pStartFrame) ;
}
   
int16_t* pStart = (int16_t*)pStartFrame, *pEnd = (int16_t*)pEndFrame;
int32_t value = SHRT_MAX;
while(pStart <= pEnd)
{
value = *pStart * kfVolume;
if(value > SHRT_MAX)
{
value = SHRT_MAX;
}
  
if(value < SHRT_MIN)
{
value = SHRT_MIN;
}
*pStart = value;
++pStart;
}
}

Answer (score 0):

```
My code to set new volume for decoded buffer is - 



  void FFMpegPlayer::UpdateVolumeForFrames(uint8_t* pStartFrame, uint8_t* pEndFrame, const float kfVolume)
    {
        if(kfVolume <= 0.0f)
        {
        memset(pStartFrame, 0, pEndFrame - pStartFrame) ;
        }

        int16_t* pStart = (int16_t*)pStartFrame, *pEnd = (int16_t*)pEndFrame;
        int32_t value = SHRT_MAX;
        while(pStart <= pEnd)
        {
        value = *pStart * kfVolume;
        if(value > SHRT_MAX)
        {
        value = SHRT_MAX;
        }

        if(value < SHRT_MIN)
        {
        value = SHRT_MIN;
        }
        *pStart = value;
        ++pStart;
        }
    }

Code to setup volume filter-
ret = avfilter_graph_create_filter(&fil_volume,
                                           avfilter_get_by_name("volume"), "volume",
                                           NULL, NULL, pVideoState->pAudioGraph);
        if (ret < 0)
            goto end;
        pVideoState->fCurrentVolume = 0.5f ;
        // Setting default volume value
        {
            AVDictionary* options_dict = nullptr;
            av_dict_set(&options_dict, "volume", AV_STRINGIFY(0.5f), 0);
            ret = avfilter_init_dict(fil_volume, &options_dict);
            av_dict_free(&options_dict);
            void *vol = (fil_volume->priv);
        }
```

Comment: i fixed it, i was passing AV_STRINGIFY(0.5f), it should be AV_STRINGIFY(0.5)